# Pandas: saving timedelta to Parquet

Tags: pandas

Looks like Pandas doesn't translate Pandas [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) to Parquet [INTERVAL](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#interval):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'seconds': 30}])
>>> df.to_parquet('/tmp/test.parquet') # so far so good
>>> df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.seconds, unit='seconds')
>>> df.to_parquet('/tmp/test.parquet')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  / ... /
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Unhandled type for Arrow to Parquet schema conversion: duration[ns]
>>>
```

Is this simply a missing feature? Am I wrong to expect `timedelta` to be saved as `INTERVAL`? Which format would you recommend if my dataframe is quite large (500mb) but I'll read it back to Pandas - `.to_pickle()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes missing feature. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-6780

you could try `engine=fastparquet`